# How to mock sqlalchemy query filter in python unit tests

Tags: python, postgresql, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, mocking

I am trying to mock the sqlalchemy query filter below:

```
def row2dict(row):
    d = {}
    for column in row.__table__.columns:
        d[column.name] = getattr(row, column.name)

    return d

data=db.query(someModel).filter(someModel.fileName == "myfile")
for row in data:
      a=row2dict(row)
```

where db is the session.

I tried with UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock() to insert mock data and use it as a session , that can be filtered using this query, but the control never goes inside for loop as it seems data is empty.

Then how to mock the query filter so that it returns some data and goes inside for loop to convert to dict ??

Answer (score 4):

You need just to patch the `Query.filter()` method. Here is an example:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base = declarative_base(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


class SomeModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_model'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    file_name = Column(String())


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


class ExampleTest(TestCase):
    def test_example(self):
        # let's check that the database is empty
        self.assertEqual(0, len(session.query(SomeModel).all()))

        # patch filter() method. example with static result:
        with patch(
            'sqlalchemy.orm.Query.filter',
            return_value=[
                dict(id=1, file_name='first'),
                dict(id=2, file_name='second'),
            ],
        ):
            records = session.query(SomeModel).filter(SomeModel.file_name.in_(['first', 'second']))
            self.assertEqual(
                records,
                [
                    dict(id=1, file_name='first'),
                    dict(id=2, file_name='second'),
                ]
            )

        # example with dynamic result
        with patch(
            'sqlalchemy.orm.Query.filter',
            side_effect=[
                [dict(id=1, file_name='first')],
                [dict(id=2, file_name='second')],
            ],
        ):
            # first call
            self.assertEqual(
                session.query(SomeModel).filter(SomeModel.file_name == 'first'),
                [
                    dict(id=1, file_name='first'),
                ]
            )

            # second call
            self.assertEqual(
                session.query(SomeModel).filter(SomeModel.file_name == 'second'),
                [
                    dict(id=2, file_name='second'),
                ]
        )
```

Result:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... collected 1 item
...::ExampleTest::test_example PASSED                       [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 0.16s ===============================

Process finished with exit code 0
```